# CountVectorizer' object has no attribute 'get_feature_names_out'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Why do i keep getting this error? I tried different versions of anaconda 3 but did not manage to get it done. What should i install to work it properly? I used sklearn versions from 0.20 - 0.23.

### Error message: [image]

### Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import plotly.express as px
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from collections import Counter
from wordcloud import WordCloud

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(2,2), analyzer='word')
sparse_matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(df['content'][:2000])
frequencies = sum(sparse_matrix).toarray()[0]
ngrams = pd.DataFrame(frequencies, index=vectorizer.get_feature_names_out(), columns=['frequency'])
ngrams = ngrams.sort_values(by='frequency', ascending=False)
ngrams
```

Comment: see the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76117262/countvectorizer-object-has-no-attribute-get-feature-names-how-to-fix-this

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You are using an old version of scikit-learn. If I'm not mistaken, `get_feature_names_out()` was only introduced in version 1.0.

Upgrade to a newer version, or, to get similar functionality in an earlier version, you can use [`get_feature_names()`](https://scikit-learn.org/0.22/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.get_feature_names).

Comment: You are right, i wasn't paying attention to that. Thanks a lot, appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

for me get_feature_names() gave error and get_feature_names_out() works perfectly.
I am using,
Name: scikit-learn
Version: 1.3.2
Summary: A set of python modules for machine learning and data mining
Home-page: http://scikit-learn.org