# 'CountVectorizer' object has no attribute 'get_feature_names' --how to fix this error

Tags: python

```
AttributeError
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-0de0e03e3155> in <cell line: 8>()
      6 
      7 # get the feature names
----> 8 features = cv.get_feature_names()
      9 
     10 # create a DataFrame from the bag of words representation

AttributeError: 'CountVectorizer' object has no attribute 'get_feature_names'
```

---

```
# create a CountVectorizer object
cv = CountVectorizer()

# fit and transform the data using CountVectorizer
X = cv.fit_transform(df['lemmatized_text']).toarray()

# get the feature names
features = cv.get_feature_names()

# create a DataFrame from the bag of words representation
df_bow = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=features)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using a relatively recent version of `sklearn`, then `CountVectorizer` has renamed the function you're trying to use as `get_feature_names_out`.

Try:

```py
# create a CountVectorizer object
cv = CountVectorizer()

# fit and transform the data using CountVectorizer
X = cv.fit_transform(df['lemmatized_text']).toarray()

# get the feature names
features = cv.get_feature_names_out()

# create a DataFrame from the bag of words representation
df_bow = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=features)
```

This is straight from the stable version's [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html).